# misplaced forms and sidebar

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, sidebar

i 'm having a problem with the side bar when i call the side bar the froms drop down and above it an empty space as you can see in the pic i used angular materiel to generate the sidebar.the side bar works just fine except for the forms drops down(https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0k6U.png)
and this is the code of the forms the line i commented it is the call of side bar :

```
//<app-accueil></app-accueil>
<form [formGroup]="addressForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 
  <mat-card class="shipping-card">
    
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>Demande de crédit</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput #postalCode placeholder="CIN" type="number" formControlName="company">
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Nom" formControlName="firstName">
            <mat-error *ngIf="addressForm.controls['firstName'].hasError('required')">
              First name is <strong>required</strong>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Prénom" formControlName="lastName">
            <mat-error *ngIf="addressForm.controls['lastName'].hasError('required')">
              Last name is <strong>required</strong>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Address" formControlName="address"></textarea>
            <mat-error *ngIf="addressForm.controls['address'].hasError('required')">
              Address is <strong>required</strong>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row" *ngIf="hasUnitNumber">
        <div class="col">
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Address 2" formControlName="address2"></textarea>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="Fiche de P" formControlName="city">
            
            <mat-error *ngIf="addressForm.controls['city'].hasError('required')">
              City is <strong>required</strong>
            </mat-error>
            
          </mat-form-field>
          <button>ajouter fichier</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <mat-select placeholder="assurance de vie" formControlName="state">
              
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error *ngIf="addressForm.controls['state'].hasError('required')">
              State is <strong>required</strong>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <button>ajouter fichier</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Enregistre</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
</form>
```

and this is the code of the side bar  :

```
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <button
    mat-icon-button
    *ngIf="sidenav.mode === 'over'"
    (click)="sidenav.toggle()"
  >
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!sidenav.opened"> menu </mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="sidenav.opened"> close </mat-icon>
  </button>
  APP
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav="matSidenav" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    

    

    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/form">Demande de crédit</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="">Etude de crédit</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="">Tableau d'amortissement</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="">Echéancier de rembourssement</a>
      <span class="slide">
      
      </span>
    </mat-nav-list>

   

    <mat-divider></mat-divider>

    <button mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/help">
      
      <span>Logout</span>
    </button>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div class="content mat-elevation-z8">
      
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Include the framework in your question title to be more specific a first glance